# C++ - How to define userdatum with Lua table as member?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-userdata, lua-c++-connection

I have a userdatum called LuaSettings. This `userdatum`, except functions, has one member - `raw`. The `raw` member is a common Lua table. The usage of this is following:

1. First, userdatum is pushed on the stack as variable `settings`
2. Then Lua file is executed and the userdatum gets modified.

```lua
-- LuaSettings:register function modifies the data.raw table
settings:register {
    {
        name = "Fuzz",
        hello = "world"
    },
    {
        name = "Buzz"
        hello = "there"
    }
}

-- User is allowed to do something like this as well:
settings.raw["Fuzz"].hello = ""
```

3. After execution is finished, the `settings.raw` table is used by C++ code.

How to do this? Is this even possible? How do I define the size of this userdatum?

Comment: Why do you need userdata here? Let `settings` be usual Lua table, you can store it in the registry (and store its ref in some `int` C variable).